# How do I have an image, with two clickable regions, each with text displaying?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I know it's probably best to have two buttons on top of the image - my problem is the buttons themselves should be invisible, but the text on the buttons should be visible???

EDIT: sorry, found an option 30 secs after posting! If you set button to type to 'Custom', you can get text displaying without anything other than the text....

Comment: Instead of editing your question to provide the answer, you should just post it as an answer (it is both allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIButton may be not the best solution. If a performance issues occur (animation is not smooth anymore) you should implement your own view and handle tap events (with UIGestureRecognizer for example). But for the first prototype UIButton will be good enough in any case.